# Maven command to push all dependencies in .m2 to a newly created empty repository(like nexus)

Tags: maven, azure-devops, artifactory, nexus, remote-repository

I have setup a new remote repository which is in a offline system (In intranet, without internet connectivity). Now I want to know if there is a Maven command to push all artifacts(dependencies-like spring boot starter, spring boot maven plugin, jacoco etc) which are in .m2 folder of same machine to newly created nexus/azure devops artifacts repository. As the system is offline, the new repo can't be connected to maven central. I know the mvn deploy command, but how to use it to move all dependencies from .m2 like spring boot starter parent and all child dependencies ?

Comment: A system might be offline without direct internet access which is in most corporate environments like that but no access to a local repository manager does not make sense?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't make sense. Local repository manager should be connected to internet to cache the dependencies. But, still I want to know if there is a possibility of uploading everything that you have in .m2 folder to local repository manager using some maven command ? Something like – mvn deploy:deploy-file -DpomFile=<path-to-pom> \
  -Dfile=<path-to-file> \
  -DrepositoryId=<id-to-map-on-server-section-of-settings.xml> \
  -Durl=<url-of-the-repository-to-deploy>. But it should upload the complete dependency tree.

Comment: So I wonder where does the local repository get its artifacts from? At some point you need an internet connection.

Comment: Local repository (.m2) has been copied there with all the artifacts that were needed and we don't need anything new. Now, is there a way to push everything to repository manager running on the same machine from .m2?

Comment: No, that's why I am trying to figure out a different way for you. So where and how did you download the content of the local repository?

Comment: When you say "remote repository" do you mean a proxy?  It basically sounds like you want a hosted repo, so wanted to make sure.

Comment: Yes, you can find more details in previous comments.  Thanks.

Comment: @Xerxis It would be great if you could answer my questions, otherwise I cannot help you.

Comment: @JF Meier We have on premise setup of AzureDevops, (not connected to internet).  Recently I tried to configure CI/CD pipeline there as Azure Devops provides support for CI/CD. I copied .M2 folder on the build server where AzureDevops is installed using pendrive and configured CI pipeline.  Everything is working fine and the build is getting generated. But now I want to move contents of .m2 (all the dependencies) to Azure Artifacts repository,   Which works in a similar way to repository manager. Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

So, on that machine, where the `.m2` folder is there, how did you get the artifacts?

Did you pull them from a company Nexus/Artifactory? Then I would just proxy that Nexus/Artifactory in your Azure Artifacts (instead of copying artifacts around).

If you got them directly from the internet, but for some reason, your Azure Artifacts cannot see the internet, I would put the `.m2/repository` folder as a Maven repository into some directory on the server and define a proxy in Azure Artifacts on that directory.

If you really need to copy all those artifacts into Azure Artifacts, then you probably need to write your own program for that.